# selenium2:Selenium WebDriver : Select one option from Image Drop Down list Box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have Image `DropDown` ListBox in my project. If I move the mouse over the menu, I will get 3 options in that. I need to select one of the option from the Listed menu. I am new to Selenium web driver. Please help to to fix this. I have tried this selection in `IE` as well as `FireFox`.
Only Mouse move will work over the menu. Even If I click nothing is happening (I mean I am not able to see the `Dropdown` List).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I have fix using below code.

```
WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin"));
WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("Element1_xpath"));
WebElement e3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Element2_xpath"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(e1).clickAndHold().build().perform();      
action.moveToElement(e2).clickAndHold().build().perform();
action.moveToElement(e3).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use driver.Mouse API functions.
Fyi: here driver is the instance of your driver.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me try with Mouse API also.